# AWS Lambda Concurrency Artificial throttling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I have a simple lambda function that recursively traverses a tree structure. At each node in the tree, a few database calls are executed (look up to see if the current object exists, possible create and update parent node record with knowledge of child node.) and lambda calls itself (creating a new lambda execution) passing the list of connected child nodes.

the tree we are traversing isn't massive but is big enough to hit our concurrency almost immediately.

what are solutions to throttle the lambda so we avoid concurrency issues.

a few thoughts:

using a queue system: have a first in first out queue that does the work.
- the pain here is you lose the connection to the parent
- size of the message in sqs is very limited.
- will have to watch execution time to make sure it dies before it runs out of time.

using sns to artificially throttle the requests. (This doesn't seem to be the right approach but people have mentioned it online.) adding an sns call adds more processing time (costs more) but still will call the same number of lambdas at a slower pace.
- the pain here is we have a limited size with the message. (we are passing down all children in each node traversal.) 
- it will cost more in the long run throwing in extra processing just to slow things down a bit.

are there other strictly serverless solutions without upping our concurrency abilities? ideas thoughts?

Comment: To resolve the SQS message limit size (256KB), perhaps you could write the relevant data to DynamoDB, using a guid as key, and simply enqueue the guid to your FIFO queue.

Comment: Use the new "fargate" service and don't spawn a job for each node. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to move the heavy lifting (recursive function) from lambdas to containers.

### Setup

#### Batch Setup

Instead of your recursive function living in a lambda it will be stored in a container within AWS [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). That container will then be associated with an AWS [Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) job that can be queued on demand.

#### Lambda

When your data arrives at the lambda it will no longer begin to be parsed. Instead, the lambda will launch a batch job and pass the data to that job.

#### Container

The code inside your container will contain your recursive function. Here you have two options.

1. Batch jobs don't have timeout limits so you can do all the recursive processing within the job.
2. For each recursive step, the container can start a new batch job and pass that branch of data (if parallel processing / reduced processing time are desired)

### Returning Data

Depending on the goals of your system the processed data might need to be consumed in different ways. From a batch job, it can not be passed to the original lambda. However, that may not be necessary or other techniques such as step functions, table events can be used to facilitate the return of data.